# Netbeans 15 + PHP. How to view a complete list of code editor hints across the project?

Tags: php, netbeans

Is there a way to view a list of all Netbeans code editor hints across my whole project, as opposed to just a single file at a time? The only way I know of viewing these hints is the warning icon in the left-hand margin of the editor windows.

I am talking about the built-in PHP hints defined in **Tools > Options > Editor > Hints**:

[image: Screenshot of Netbeans Options dialog]

I am not talking about PHPStan, or any other external static analysis tools, which is what the majority of existing answers seem to be about.

I have already tried the **Source > Inspect** menu option which I don't believe is relevant as does not apply to these code editor hints, only to external tools.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RiggsFolly [This question is on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It is about _"software tools commonly used by programmers"_ and _"is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"_. There are tens of thousands of valid on topic questions about IDE usage on SO, so why do you view this particular one as off topic? Also, asking for a verifiable example for this question makes no sense because it is about the functionality of the IDE, not PHP code.